# WolframAlpha and I don't agree on $( xy\sin y )/(3x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

WolframAlpha claims that the following limit does not exist:

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2} $$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(xysiny)%2F(3x%5E2%2By%5E2)+as+%7Bx-%3E0,+y-%3E0%7D

However, I just proved that its limit is zero. Here is how:

1. $2|(\sqrt{3} x)(y)| \leq 3x^2 + y^2 $ by AM-GM.
2. Therefore, $ |xy \sin{y}| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt3}(3x^2+y^2)|\sin{y}|$
3. And so, $ 0 \leq |\frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2}| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}|\sin{y}|$
4. The one on the left and the right both go to zero as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$; therefore our expression in the middle must also converge to zero.
5. Finally, because $|\frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2}|$ converges to zero, $\frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2}$ converges to zero as well.

I am absolutely sure my proof is logical and correct, especially because WolframAlpha says '0' to this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(xy%5E2)%2F(3x%5E2%2By%5E2)+as+%7Bx-%3E0,+y-%3E0%7D .

However, my textbook also claims it to be nonexistent.

**What is the limit?**

**If it really is zero, then why does WolframAlpha claim it to be nonexistent?**

**If it isn't zero, where did I go wrong?**

Comment: WA says "limit does not exist, is path dependent, or cannot be determined". This is different to "limit does not exist".

Comment: @gammatester oops....this is a blatant mistake on my part. Though it is intriguing why wolframalpha fails to determine the limit, it is also true that I never asked that question. I will accept the quickest answer made.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Without knowing the details, I guess the reason why WA fails to get $0$, is that 'it'  (i.e. the interpreter/algorithm) cannot determine the limit. I do not assume that 'it' means that the limit does not exist. And see also Somos' interpretation.

Comment: The current documentation for the Wolfram Language used by Wolfram|Alpha shows that Limit[f[x,y],{x->0,y->0}] is interpreted as a **nested** limit, while Limit[f[x,y],{x,y}->{0,0}] is interpreted a the multivariate limit. It gives $0$ for both limits.

Comment: I would recommend using [Wolfram Development Platform](https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com/app/) (go to "create a new notebook") instead of Alpha. As Somos pointed out, it gives correct results in both cases (as would full version of Wolfram Mathematica).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limit is $0$. You can also prove that using the fact that$$\frac{xy\sin y}{3x^2+y^2}=\frac{xy^2}{3x^2+y^2}\times\frac{\sin y}y,$$that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy^2}{3x^2+y^2}=0$$ and that $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin y}y=1$.

Comment: But you haven't answered the question. Why does WA claim it's nonexistent?

Comment: I cannot answer that, since I don't know the algorithm used by Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

To see the given limit exists and is zero, one may just employ [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), obtaining
$$
\left|\frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2} \right|=\left|\frac{xy\sin{y}}{\color{red}{2x^2}+x^2+y^2} \right|\le \left|\frac{xy\sin{y}}{x^2+y^2} \right|= \frac{r^2\left|\cos \theta \sin \theta \right|\left|\sin{\left(r \sin \theta\right)} \right|}{r^2}\le \left|r \sin \theta\right|\le r
$$ where we have made used of
$$
\left|\sin \theta \right|\le1, \qquad\left|\cos \theta \sin \theta \right|\le1, \qquad|\sin x |\le |x|, \qquad x \to 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have that

$$\frac{xy\sin{y}}{3x^2+y^2}=\frac{\sin y}y\frac{xy^2}{3x^2+y^2} \to 1 \cdot 0=0$$

indeed by $x=\frac r {\sqrt 3} \cos \theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ we can easily show that $\frac{xy^2}{3x^2+y^2} \to 0$.